# Syntax error, file reader problems, trouble with setters. Complicated problems

Tags: java, syntax, filereader, setter, getter

I'll post the full code below. After my last post I attempted to have it auto format. I hope it's not too difficult to read. Anyway...the problems....

I have three issues.

**1st) Line 113**

BufferedReader withdrawalFile = Files.newBufferedReader(Withdrawals, Charset.defaultCharset());

There is an error "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token."

I don't understand this error at all. If you look on line 94, you'll see I've written the same line of code for "deposits", which does not have the same problem.

**2nd) Line 119**

userAccount.setWithdrawal(userWithdrawal);

There is an error asking me to make a local variable for userAccount. I assume this is connected to the error from above, but I've tried looking for a curly brace or something. I can't find anything.

3rd) Errors with my setters?

The account amount is supposed to finish with $610.17. It ends with 500.00 The file reader should edit the amount in the account to go up $110.17, but it isn't and I don't know why.

Also, any advice on how to make my code cleaner is welcome.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.nio.charset.Charset;
 import java.nio.file.Files;
 import java.nio.file.Path;
 import java.nio.file.Paths;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Savings {
     private double accountAmount;
     private double interestRate; 
     private int months;

//Provides access to interestRate, accountAmount, and months with getters
// and setters
public void setBeginning(double testAccount){
    this.accountAmount= testAccount;}

public void setAccountAmount(double userInput){
    this.accountAmount = userInput;
}

public void setWithdrawal(double withdrawal){
    this.accountAmount = (accountAmount- withdrawal) ;}

public void setDeposit(double deposit){
    this.accountAmount = (accountAmount + deposit);}

public void setMonths(int userMonths){
    this.months = userMonths;}

public void setInterest(double userInterest){
    this.interestRate= userInterest;}

public int getMonths(){
    return this.months;}

public double getInterest(){
    return this.interestRate;}

public double getAccount(){
    return this.accountAmount;      }


 // Main method. Creates a savings account (userAccount) gets an interest rate and # of months
 //from the user.
 // Reads pre-written deposit and withdrawal files, account should end up at $610.17

public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
     String stringInterest, stringMonths;
     int userMonths;
     double userInterest, preInterestAccount;

     Savings userAccount = new Savings();

     stringInterest = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the monthly interest rate "
        + "on your account?\n Put it in decimal terms.\n (Ex: 1.0 would be 100%)");

 if (stringInterest == null) {
    System.exit(0); }
     while (stringInterest.trim().length()== 0 || Double.parseDouble(stringInterest) < 0){
         stringInterest= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You did not enter a valid value.\n" +
        "Please enter a valid value for interest.");
         if (stringInterest == null){
             System.exit(0);} 
     }//ends the while

stringMonths = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many months will the money be "
        + "in your account?");
if (stringMonths == null) {
    System.exit(0); }
while (stringMonths.trim().length()== 0 || Integer.parseInt(stringMonths) < 0){
    stringInterest= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You did not enter a valid value.\n" +
        "Please enter a valid value for interest.");
    if (stringInterest == null){
        System.exit(0);} 
}//ends the while

userMonths=Integer.parseInt(stringMonths);
userInterest=Double.parseDouble(stringInterest);

userAccount.setMonths(userMonths);
userAccount.setInterest(userInterest);;
userAccount.setBeginning(500.00);

Path Deposists = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Owner\\workspace\\BankAccount\\"
        + "src\\Deposists.txt");


BufferedReader depositFile = Files.newBufferedReader(Deposists, Charset.defaultCharset());
String dLine;

// read each line
        while((dLine = depositFile.readLine()) != null) {
            double userDeposit;

            userDeposit=Double.parseDouble(dLine);
            userAccount.setDeposit(userDeposit);
            }
        depositFile.close();}



 Path Withdrawals = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Owner\\workspace\\BankAccount\\"
                + "src\\Withdrawals.txt");

 String wLine;

 BufferedReader withdrawalFile = Files.newBufferedReader(Withdrawals, Charset.defaultCharset());

     while((wLine = withdrawalFile.readLine()) != null) {
                    double userWithdrawal;

                    userWithdrawal=Double.parseDouble(wLine);
                    userAccount.setWithdrawal(userWithdrawal);
                    }
                withdrawalFile.close();


        preInterestAccount = userAccount.getAccount();
        userAccount.setAccountAmount((userAccount.getAccount()*(1+userAccount.getInterest())*
        (userAccount.getMonths())));

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The interest rate is "+ (userAccount.getInterest()*100)
        +"%.\n"+ "Your money was in the account for " + userAccount.getMonths()+" months.\n"
        + "The balance on your account before interest is "+ preInterestAccount + ".\n"
        + "The final balance of your account is  "+ (userAccount.getAccount()) +".");

    }//ends main method
```

}

Comment: "There is an error asking me to make a local variable for userAccount." No there isn't. Post the *actual* error message. If you have compilation errors it is impossible to also have runtime errors. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP he's stating that the IDE is saying there is a syntactical error.

Comment: "After my last post I attempted to have it auto format. I hope it's not too difficult to read." The autoformatter can only do its work if the code is free of syntax errors. Yours isn't. You should not rely on this feature and make sure yourself that your code is formatted in a somewhat decent way.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Precisely, so how can there possibly be execution problems when the code doesn't even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two closing brackets in the while loop below. This is causing the error on line 113 and line 119. Just remove the bracket after `depositFile.close();`.

```
    // read each line
    while((dLine = depositFile.readLine()) != null) {
        double userDeposit;

        userDeposit=Double.parseDouble(dLine);
        userAccount.setDeposit(userDeposit);
        } // <--------------- HERE --------------------
    depositFile.close();} // <------------ AND HERE ---
```

Also, you have an unnecessary semicolon, this won't cause errors but it shouldn't be there:

```
userAccount.setMonths(userMonths);
userAccount.setInterest(userInterest);; //<-------- HERE
userAccount.setBeginning(500.00);
```

To make your code cleaner: if you're using an IDE, like Eclipse, then there should be an option to auto-format your code. In Eclipse it's `Source->format`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It was actually the one after the depositFile.close. The other bracket is needed. But thank you.